# Вопрос насчёт утечки памяти

Tags: visual-c++

Нет ли в функции **input_ptr()** никаких утечек, так как переменную, созданную ей можно ***удалить*** с помощью delete, так и free()?

```
// заголовок clsio.h
template<typename T>
T* input_ptr()
{
    T* result = new T;
    std::cin >> *result;
    return result;
}

//main.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "clsio.h"

int main() {
    int* number = input_ptr<int>();

    std::cout << *number + 5;
    delete number;
    
    // number = 0;
    // free(number);
}
```

Comment: Утечка только в том смысле, что вы можете забыть удалить руками... А вот удалять — через `delete`, никакого `free`.

Comment: Спасибо. Если бы я создавал через malloc(), то нужно было бы удалять через free()?

Comment: Да, но `malloc` в C++ противопоказан. Он понятия не имеет о конструкторах... Как и `free` о деструкторах.

Comment: Насчёт минусов malloc я в курсе